# What connector is this and what crimping tool do I need for it?

Tags: identification, connector

I need to replace an industrial server fan on some network kit. It is a four-pin PWM fan with tach. The replacement fan I am getting doesn't have a connector on it, so I need to crimp one on.

The four cables I need to crimp are each UL 1061 AWG 24 per the datasheet of the fan.

The connector has a locking tab on it, to lock into the socket. It is approx 9 mm wide and 3.5 mm thick (approx 5.1 mm thick when including the locking tab).

The pitch is 2mm.

Please advise:

1. Which connector and socket combo this?
2. Which crimping pins are these?
3. What to crimping tool to get for this?

[image: connector]

[image]

Comment: cut and splice the wires instead

Comment: What is the pitch of the pins, i.e. distance from center to center.

Comment: If you're going to use it on your own projects, that presupposes you have the mating connector, and therefore know what plugs into it. Is that not the case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi all thanks for the replies and help. No i haven't got any connector yet, I am replacing a fan and saw the connector to be easy to work with, so would consider it or newer equivalent on other projects.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be Molex Sherlock 35507, parts 0355070400 and 0353620450.

I'm not sure if their website is malfunctioning at the moment, or they're actively delisting the family, but the [product page](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/355070400) is tagged "New Business Not Supported".  I wouldn't suggest using it on new projects.